# different, visual appearances of same binary app installed on same iOS version

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Recently, I have released a new version iPhone app, but as the following pictures, the back button of pages and the general button respectively have difference appearances in spite of the same iOS version(v8.4)

I must admit that I do not have deep understanding about iPhone app, and my iPhone app has been built on the Xamarin platform.

Does anyone know why this is occurred?

### Back button

[image]
[image]

### general button

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the one device has button shapes turned on. This is an accessibility feature. If you can, check `Settings` → `Accessibility` → `Button Shapes` on that device.

Comment: I see... Thank you for your answer.